# Array.some() function did not matched for undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

```
var array = [3,4,5];
delete array[1];
console.log(array);
console.log(array[1]);
array.some(element => {
    console.log(element);
    return element === 3
})
array.some(element => {
    console.log(element);
    return element === undefined
})
```

PS: In the image below `array` for above code is taken as `a` and `element` is taken as `b`

[image]

Why does Array.some() function did not matched for undefined at index 1? Does it handles undefined differently?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#deleting_array_elements

Comment: The length is left unchanged, but the **array has only 2 elements**. So, when you use `.some(fn)`, `fn` is applied only on those two existing elements. Had you used `a[1] = undefined` instead, it would work as you expected. _Also, prefer to post code instead of print_

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question "needs details or clarity," you posted an image instead of code which is inherently inaccessible to those with visual problems, and it's non-searchable to make the question harder to find for others with similar problems in the future. Please, post the code as text, ideally as `code` or a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 3):

The .some doesn't check the empty index  The undefined must be statically written

```js
const myArr = [1,,3];
console.log(myArr)

myArr.some(elem => console.log(elem))

 myArr[1] = undefined;
console.log(myArr)

myArr.some(elem => console.log(elem))
```

If you want to detect empty indices

this should work

```js
const myArr = [1,,3];


function hadEmptyIndex(arr){
  
  for(const member of arr){
    if(typeof member === "undefined") return true
  }
  
  return false
}


console.log(hadEmptyIndex(myArr))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are not iterating over `empty` values, so you can't really check if the value is equal to `undefined` or not.

Once you delete an item from an array, the array methods such as `some`, `forEach`, and etc will skip the item in the iteration.

What you can do instead is setting the element to `null`, then it's gonna be iterable:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a[0] = null // [ null, 2, 3 ]
a.some(b => b === null) // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Great question, array.some() function only iterate over indexes with assign values,

`callbackFn is invoked only for indexes of the array with assigned values. It is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.`

for further reading [Read Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion is: **empty and undefined aren't the same thing**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#deleting_array_elements

The length is left unchanged after delete, but the **array has only 2 elements**. So, when you use `.some(fn)`, `fn` is applied only on those two existing elements. Had you used a[1] = undefined instead, it would work as you expected.

Compare, for example:

```js
let a = [3, 4, 5];
console.table(a);

/* outputs
  (index) | Value
  0       | 3
  1       | 4
  2       | 5
*/

delete a[1];
console.table(a);

/* outputs -- notice there's only 2 elements
  (index) | Value
  0       | 3
  2       | 5

 NOTE: FireFox shows differently:
  (index) | Value
  0       | 3
  1       | 
  2       | 5
*/

let b = [3, 4, 5];
b[1] = undefined;
console.table(b);

/* outputs
  (index) | Value
  0       | 3
  1       | undefined
  2       | 5
*/
```

You can also reproduce an array with an `empty` index declaring it like `let a = [3,,5];`

Also, just to add, **empty is not something really standard in javascript** (the behavior is, but not the name). Chrome DevTools shows simply as `empty` or `empty × n`, but FireFox shows as `<n empty slots>`.